# Kernel Support | Processors List

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, cpu, database

Where can I find the supported Processors for each Kernel Version?
For example

```
(KBL Processors) is only supported for Kernel Kernel 4.5
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Linux-supported_computer_architectures lists the supported architecures.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a valid Linux installation which has the Linux source code (well, at least the headers) then you can see the complete list of supported CPUs using the `ls` command like so:

```
$ ls -1 /usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-20/arch
alpha
arc
arm
arm64
blackfin
c6x
cris
frv
h8300
hexagon
ia64
Kconfig   <-- not a CPU (obviously?)
m32r
m68k
metag
microblaze
mips
mn10300
nios2
openrisc
parisc
powerpc
riscv
s390
score
sh
sparc
tile
um
unicore32
x86
xtensa
```

Tweak the version as required, or use an asterisk:

```
$ ls -1 /usr/src/linux-headers-*/arch
```

Just note that with an asterisk you may get multiple copies of the list, one per version installed on your system.

Answer (score 1):

http://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/ link has the change log for each kernel. 
Once you download the kernel you could also look into arch/ folder to see the list of processors supported.